# Task parallel library and multiple parallel tasks

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

How does TPL handle multiple Parallel invocations?

Example: I want to process two unrelated collections in parallel.
(assume that processing for one item in each collection take very long time)

Currently I do it like this:

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => Parallel.ForEach(collection1,...),
                () => Parallel.ForEach(collection2,...))
```

This works but I am curious how the TPL scheduler will deal with the 3 separate invokes.

Should I do it differently?

Answer (score 2):

2 important things first:

- If you have long running iterations in a Parallel.For / Parallel.ForEach workload (or any type of blocking in the loop delegate), you should always specify the concurrency level using ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism. This is because the parallel loop implementations were optimized for finer grained workloads, and they may end up injecting extra worker threads when they encounter long running iterations.
- By launching simultaneous parallel loops you are already forcing the 2 loops to compete for CPU resources. So even if you didn't have long running iterations, it would be wise to load balance them explicitly by limiting each loop's MaxDOP (practically I'd go with Environment.ProcessorCount / 2 for each)

To answer your original questions:

> *...3 separate invokes...*

Yes, TPL will handle 3 or more separate Parallel.Invokes just fine. It's even optimized not to waste threads in a nested parallelism scenario like this one.

> *Should I do it differently?*

At the very least you should use MaxDOP as I explained above. But you may want to pick a different DOP strategy based on these:

- Do the collections need roughly equal amounts of work?
- Do you have any blocking in the loop delegates?

Comment: Thanks. Why is spinning up extra threads for long iterations a bad thing? There are a lot of blocking (i.e. IO) in the delegates. Wouldn't a lower MaxDOP increase the risk that all threads are waiting?

Comment: It'd be worse if the iterations are CPU bound (i.e. non-blocking), in that case you'd get more threads than # of cores, which leads to a pretty inefficient fight.

Comment: However if the iterations are blocking, then it's usually beneficial to have *some* oversubscription as you also said. TPL unfortunately doesn't have a mechanism for keeping track of how many parallel iterations are blocked and controlling DOP accordingly. Therefore it's best if the oversubscription level is set by the programmer based on an estimation of the blocking characteristics.

Comment: It's not true that "it would be worse if the iterations are CPU bound".  TPL uses a "hill climbing" algorithm to allocate threads avoiding over-subscription.  MSDN says "Hill-climbing algorithms were introduced to quickly determine and adjust to the optimal number of threads for the current workload."